# Deactivating Facebook but keeping my SO account

Tags: support, user-accounts, facebook

The two are linked, i.e. I sign into SO using my Facebook credentials. If I were to deactive my Facebook account, what options do I have available to me for still signing in to my original SO account as opposed to creating a new one?

Comment: Add another OpenID to your account. Go to your profile page and then "my logins".

Comment: Was unaware of OpenID at all. Thanks very much.